# jqPlot plot object to different div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I am generating a graph for one div, and I want to display that exact same graph on another div?

I have:
    `var plot = $.jqplot (firstDiv , data,options)`

And I want to plot this to another to another div, is that possible assuming i don't have `data` or `options` available to me? Would I be able to use the `plot` variable to draw to the secondDiv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the plot variable like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var plot = $.jqplot ('firstDiv', data,options);
  $.jqplot ('anotherDiv', plot.data,plot.options);
});
```

Comment: I get "Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object Object]". My data is of the form [[,],[],.....].

Comment: it seems to work on this fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/dnHGB/](http://jsfiddle.net/dnHGB/)

Comment: I don't seem to see any charts generated in the link you've posted.

Comment: for some reason ie can't display the jqplot

Comment: don't see it in chrome, firefox or ie.